# Setting up hive with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up the hive. I am using this guide: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted.html and I'm stuck at setting up /tmp and /user/hive/warehouse dirs. First of all, it seems to me a little bit strange that hive requires to change my /tmp dir to HDFS. Won't this affect other apps which are using /tmp dir? Anyway, I would like to change /tmp path to something different. I was hopping that I'll find config in ./hive/conf/ but there are only config template files. Where is the actual config file?

And by the way, in ./hive/bin I've found hive-config.sh. I can't find anything in wiki about this file, what does it do?

I am using the hive-0.8.1.tar.gz version.

Answer (score 3):

The /tmp dir you needed to change is located on HDFS, not your local disk. Hence, it won't affect other apps if they do not access data on HDFS.

The Hive configuration should located in its conf dir, the local configuration file is hive-install-dir/conf/hive-site.xml